# query for selecting all of the branches of a tree

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for category like this

```
id | title | parent_id
---|-------|------------
1  | cat1  |  null
2  | cat2  |  null
3  | cat3  |  1
4  | cat4  |  1
5  | cat5  |  3
6  | cat6  |  5
7  | cat7  |  6
8  | cat8  |  7
```

I want to know how can I have the main categories with their branches and a column that gives me the count branches of each tree
for example something like this for the main category cat1 :

```
cat1 => cat3 => cat5 => cat6 => cat7 => cat8
```

Thank you

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I'd recommend adding a column 'path' that you populate with the ancestor ids separated by some delimiter: "/1/3/5/6/7/8/". It costs you more complexity at writing and maintenance but you gain simple and powerful queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get all entries from the database in the form of an array.

```
select * from categories;
```

```
$name = [];
$parent = [];
$children = [];

foreach($categories as $category){
    $name[$category['id']] = $category['name'];
    
    $parent[$category['id']] = $category['parent_id'];

    if(isset($category['parent_id'])){
       $children[$category['parent_id']][] = $category['id'];
    }
}
```

Now you have children for every category in the $children[$category_id] array.

And parent for every child

To print the traversal from any child to the root.

```
$id = `any id`;

while(isset($id)){
   echo $name[$id] . " => ";
   $id = isset(parent[$id] ? parent[$id] : null); 
}
```

To get the count of children of any node.

```
echo sizeof($children[$category_id]);
```

Now, when it comes to traversal from parent to a child, there can be many options as one node can have more than one child.

I'm writing the code that picks random child and goes for the traversal to the next level.

```
$id = `any id`;

while(isset($id)){
   echo $name[$id] . " => ";
   if(isset($children[$id])){
     $idx = array_rand($children[$id], 1);
     $id = $children[$idx];
   }
   else{
      // This means you've reached the leaf node.
      $id = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear friend
I'm not sure about speed of performance from this way
Do you think it's as fast as we need for a big e-commerce website?
speed of query from database and to run these codes from PHP
Is it fast enough to use?

Comment: Yes, it is. I mean in terms of time complexity the first loop is O(n) as inside we're using map(array in PHP). And this just has to be done once. The other loop that gets the traversal runs in O(x) where x is the length of the whole traversel(from leaf to root) (and in worst case that can be n). Now this loop utilizez the map built earlier. So you build the map once, and calculate as many traversals as you want in a really efficient manner(in the order of the length of the traversal).

Comment: And yeah, obviously there could be a database query that could handle this dynamic level queries. I'm not aware of any, but there could be other people that might know :)

Comment: So yeah,this is my answer . thank you so so so much